# Запись и чтение std::list в бинарном формате

Tags: c++, файлы, list, stl, файловый-ввод-вывод

В листе содержится `std::pair<int, bool>`. Как такой лист записать в файл и считать из него?

Comment: А какой файл вы хотите — текстовый или бинарный?

Comment: Бинарный. Поскольку объём данных большой.

Comment: Если он такой большой, вы уверены, что вам подходит `std::list`? А не `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерный набросок:

```
list<pair<int,bool>> lst;

// Запись
ofstream out(filename,ios::binary);
for(const auto& x: lst)
    out.write((char*)&x,sizeof(x));

// Чтение
ifstream in(filename,ios::binary);
pair<int,bool> x;
while(in.read((char*)&x,sizeof(x)))
    lst.push_back(x);
```

Так сработает, потому что `pair<int,bool>` — просто структура от POD. Для `pair<string,bool>` это уже работать не станет.

И не забудьте все необходимые проверки :)

С `vector` *в этом случае* еще проще.

```
vector<pair<int,bool>> lst;

// Запись
ofstream out(filename,ios::binary);
out.write((char*)lst.data(),sizeof(pair<int,bool>)*lst.size());

// Чтение
ifstream in(filename,ios::binary);
size_t count = in.seekg(0,ios::end).tellg()/sizeof(pair<int,bool>);
lst.resize(count);
in.seekg(0);
in.read((char*)lst.data(),sizeof(pair<int,bool>)*count);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!